# Calculations using Triggers

Tags: sql, database, oracle

When the Table Timesheet is approved (Timesheet_approved* is Not Null) a trigger should fire which will calculate the payment for standard hours due (Payroll_standard*) and the payment due for any overtime (Payroll_overtime* = standard hours X 1.5) for the previous week on the table Payroll.

It should also calculate the pension contribution (Payroll_pension* = 10% of standard + Over time) due and then update the payroll table (working out what the next payroll id would be)

Please note * is used to point out the names of the table attributes. Tables being used/ affected are funtom_Timesheet and funtom_Payroll

So far I have the code below. However, I keep getting errors around bad variable bind:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -------------------------------------------------------------
32/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
33/3     PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

33/3     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PAYROLL_STANDARD'
34/3     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PAYROLL_OVERTIME'
35/3     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PAYROLL_PENSION'
41/1     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PAYROLL_ID'
SQL>
```

This is the trigger code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_PAYROLLCALC
After UPDATE
on funtom_Timesheet FOR EACH ROW

Declare
V_TimesheetHRS number;
V_GRADEHRS number;
V_TimesheetOT number;
v_OTGRADEHRS number;
v_payrollID number;

BEGIN

SELECT Grade_rate into V_GRADEHRS
FROM Grade join Employee on (Emp_grade = grade_id)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;

SELECT Timesheet_hours into V_TimesheetHRS
From Funtom_timesheet join Funtom_employee on (emp_ID = Timesheet_emp)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;

Select Timesheet_OT into V_TimesheetOT
From Timesheet join Employee on (emp_ID = Timesheet_emp)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;

select Sum(Grade_rate * 1.5) into v_OTGRADEHRS
from Grade join Employee on (Emp_grade = grade_id)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;


IF Timesheet_approved IS NOT NULL then
Update funtom_Payroll set
:new.Payroll_standard := V_GRADEHRS * V_TimesheetHRS;
:new.Payroll_overtime := v_OTGRADEHRS * V_TimesheetOT;
:new.Payroll_pension  := ((V_GRADEHRS * V_TimesheetHRS)+(v_OTGRADEHRS * V_TimesheetOT));
END IF;

Select MAX(Payroll_id)+1 into v_payrollID
from Payroll;

:new.Payroll_id := v_payrollID;

END;
/
```

Comment: Hello! Please go to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a question.

Comment: Please post the structure of table

Comment: And don't write about *Table Timesheet* entities (etc) without explaining what data you are actually talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `:new.<field_name>` is a readable reference to the new row in `funtom_Timesheet` whose row being updated caused this trigger to fire. Your update `funtom_Payroll` command needs field names from the `funtom_Payroll` table in the position you were referencing `:new`. You can reference the `:new` and `:old` in this update statement after the `:=`, but probably not before. If you explain what the trigger is supposed to do, I could help fix the trigger code.

Comment: When the timesheet is approved a trigger should fire which will calculate the payment for standard hours due and the payment due for any overtime for the previous week. It should also calculate the pension contribution due and then update the payroll table (working out what the next payroll id would be

Comment: Timesheet is approved (Timesheet_approved* is Not Null)calculate the payment for standard hours due (Payroll_standard*) and the payment due for any overtime (Payroll_overtime* = standard hours X 1.5) for the previous week on the table Payroll. 

It should also calculate the pension contribution (Payroll_pension* = 10% of standard + Over time) due and then update the payroll table (working out what the next payroll id would be)

Please note * is used to point out the names of the table attributes. Tables being used/ affected are funtom_Timesheet and funtom_Payroll

Comment: There are several things that could be wrong. I'll start with the first select query. From the way `v_gradehrs` was used later, it looks like you want the grade rate for the employee on the timesheet.
`SELECT Grade_rate into V_GRADEHRS
FROM Grade join Employee on (Emp_grade = grade_id)
where emp_ID = Timesheet_emp
;` Then you may want it to look like this instead, although without knowing what tables emp_grade and grade_id are in, it's tough to tell:
`SELECT Grade_rate into V_GRADEHRS
FROM Grade join Employee on (Emp_grade = grade_id)
where emp_ID = :new.Timesheet_emp
;`

Comment: The same sort of changes may need to be made to the next three select statements. Then the update statement might want to be changed to this: `IF Timesheet_approved IS NOT NULL then
insert into  funtom_Payroll (Payroll_standard,Payroll_overtime, Payroll_pension, Payroll_id)
    values (V_GRADEHRS * V_TimesheetHRS,
    v_OTGRADEHRS * V_TimesheetOT,
    ((V_GRADEHRS * V_TimesheetHRS)+(v_OTGRADEHRS * V_TimesheetOT)));
END IF;`

Comment: Error
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
13/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the
         following:
         ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
         null pragma raise return select update while with
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
         insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
         merge pipe purge
         The symbol "exit" was substituted for ";" to continue.

Comment: LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
         expecting one of the following:
         , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where
         connect